# How many requests/secound are available on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I want to deploy a node js server , and I just want to know how many requests/secound are available on free deployment , I want at least 1500/s which pricing plan should I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per their documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#network), you are only limited on the total bandwidth per month

> Network bandwidth is soft limited at 2TB per app per month

At that point, it's all dependent on how fast your application can serve responses. From their [dyno types documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types), the free tier is limited to 512mb of RAM and has up to 4 (shared) CPUs. It's entirely possible to get 1.5k req/sec with this, but it probably wouldn't be super useful.

I can't give a better other than "the hardware can definitely do it, can your app serve that much?". If not, you will probably have to move to the hobby or standard tier and potentially scale up as needed. That can be determined by viewing the **Throughput** metric graph for your app.